# Bourwer degree zero degree lemma

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

I was reading Milnor's differential topology book,in the Brouwer degree chapter.there is a famous lemma state as follows:

> If $f:M\to N$ extend to smooth map $F:X\to N$ then $\text{deg}(f,y) = 0$ for every regular value(where $\partial X =M$,all manifold are oriented,M is compact,N is connected)

1. In the proof,we take the $F^{-1}(y)$ as regular value
   submanifold,it's one-dimension compact manifold,hence exist two
   cases arc and circle,in the book,case of arc is considered just
   prove:$\text{sgn}(df_a)+\text{sgn}(df_b) = 0$ ,I don't know why
   don't consider the case of circle.(since no intersection withh
   $\partial X$) is my understanding correct?
2. the second question is the induced orientation for the arc,I don't understand why sgn of $df_{a/b}$ is induced by the map $F:X\to N$? I guess something to do with extension,but I can't make it clear

Answer (score 1):

For $1$): Indeed the boundary points of $X$, $\partial X= M$ only intersect with the simple curves

For $2$): the orientation of an arc $A$ is induced by both $X$ and $N$: let $x\in A$
and let $(v_1,...,v_{n+1})$ be a positively oriented basis for the tangent space of $X$, with $v_1$ tangent to the simple curve $A$. Then the vector $v_1$ determines the appropriate orientation for the tangent space of the simple curve $A$ if the differential map $dF_x$ send $(v_2,...,v_{n+1})$ into a positively oriented basis for $N$. Hence the sign of $df_a$ induced by the map $F$.

Comment: Why orientation of $X$ can determine the orientation of $A$?

Comment: @yili Sure, this means that the orientation for the tangent space of the simple curve $A$ will be forced to act the same way the orientation for the tangent space of $N$ is set by $dF_x$, using the basis $(v_2,...,v_{n+1})$. In return this orientation for $N$ is complely determined by our choice of a positively orientaed basis for the tangent space of $X$ at the begining. This is the chain of reasoning which leads from the orientation for $X$ determining the orientation for $A$. Basically the job of $dF_x$ is to act of the basis vectors in such a way to move the orientation from $X$ to $N$...

Comment: ...but $v_1$ is set aside for $A$!